cameraX preview view aspect ratio not working on high resolution device
need to set 16:9 / 4:3 / 1:1 aspect ratio
i use below code to do this
`       cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    imgCaptureExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
        val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()

        val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
            .also {
                it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.cameraViewer.surfaceProvider)
            }

        imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()

        val qualitySelector = QualitySelector.fromOrderedList(
            listOf(Quality.UHD, Quality.FHD, Quality.HD, Quality.SD),
            FallbackStrategy.lowerQualityOrHigherThan(Quality.SD)
        )
        val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
            .setExecutor(cameraExecutor).setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
            .build()

        videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

        val viewPort = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            ViewPort.Builder(
               Rational(9, 16), display?.rotation ?: Surface.ROTATION_0
            ).build()
        } else {
            ViewPort.Builder(
                Rational(9, 16), Surface.ROTATION_0
            ).build()
        }

        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
            .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
            .build()

        try {
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()

            val useCaseGroup = UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                .addUseCase(preview)
                .addUseCase(imageCapture!!)
                .addUseCase(videoCapture!!)
                .addUseCase(imageAnalysis)
                .setViewPort(viewPort)
                .build()


            val camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
                this, cameraSelector, preview
            )
          } catch (exc: Exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
        }

    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))

`
With viewport i can do this and it is works well. but not working as expected on high resolution device like Pixel 8 Pro, vivo v30 pro etc.

Have you used PreviewView in your XML file?

yes, setSurfaceProvider(binding.cameraViewer.surfaceProvider)
in these binding.cameraViewer is my PreviewView.

You need to use resolution selector for picking a resolution. The ViewPort is for creating the correct crop rect.

No need to use viewPort, we need to set ResolutionSelector to preview, imageCapture and imageAnalysis like this to get output size
    val resolutionSelectorBuilder = ResolutionSelector.Builder().apply {
setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy(androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9, AspectRatioStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_AUTO))
    }.build()

val preview = Preview.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelectorBuilder)
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()
                .also {
                    it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.viewfinder.surfaceProvider)
                }

            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelectorBuilder)
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
                .build()

    val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
                .setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelectorBuilder)
                .setTargetRotation(rotation)
           .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
                .build()

and set height/width of preview view as per your ratio.
in this case for 16:9 i set width to match_parent and
height to (viewfinder.width * 16) / 9
viewfinder.layoutParams.height = (viewfinder.width * 16) / 9

now you have preview view with 16:9 ratio and get captured images with these ratio also.
